# Find $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z+\frac{1}{2})^n$ converges to $f$ around $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Develop $f:\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}\to\mathbb{C}$, 
$$f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$$
 into a power series around $-\frac{1}{2}$: Find $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ $(n\in\mathbb{N}_0$) so that $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z+\frac{1}{2})^n$$ and find the radius of convergence around $-\frac{1}{2}$.

---

I don't really get it. Is this just guesswork?

Comment: Are they asking for one arbitrary of $a_n$ such that it converges? Choose $a_n = 0$; the accompanying radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: @Myridium How would that converge to the given $f(z)\,$, which is nowhere $0\,$?

Comment: @dxiv - Sorry, I found the question to be written confusingly. I understand now; they want $a_n$ to match a given function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not guess work. You simply have to compute the derivatives of $f$ at $-1/2$. Then
$$\newcommand{\of}[1]{\left({#1}\right)}\newcommand{\notwo}{\frac{-1}{2}}f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}\of{\notwo}}{n!}\of{z+\frac{1}{2}}^n$$
in a neighborhood of $-1/2$, by standard facts from complex analysis. Its radius of convergence is also known to be the distance from $-1/2$ to the closest pole of $f$.

Now we don't even have to explicitly compute the derivatives, because $f$ has a particularly nice power series.
Note that $f$ is defined by the geometric series at the origin, so $f=\frac{1}{1-z}$ where it's defined, by the usual formula for the sum of a geometric series. Now
$$\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}-\of{z+\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}\of{z+\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \of{\frac{2}{3}}^n\of{z+\frac{1}{2}}^n,$$
and this converges when $\left|\frac{2}{3}\of{z+\frac{1}{2}}\right| <1$, or when $\left|z+\frac{1}{2}\right| < \frac{3}{2}$, so $a_n =\of{\frac{2}{3}}^{n+1}$, and the series has radius of convergence $3/2$.

Comment: Nice transformation of the geometric series into another!

Comment: Oh ! I did not read jgon's answer till the end. +1

Answer (score 0):

Finding the series is simply a matter of Taylor expansion around $z=-\frac 1 2$.

$$f(z) \approx \frac 1 {n!} \left.\frac{d^n f(z)}{dz^n}\right\vert_{z=-\frac 1 2}\left(z+\frac 1 2\right)^n$$
so that
$$a_n = \frac 1 {n!} \left.\frac{d^n f(z)}{dz^n}\right\vert_{z=-\frac 1 2}$$
Are you able to solve it from here?

Answer (score 0):

As you have the function, you can do it quickly without the derivatives (although the general method can be found in the other answers). Write
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}=
\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}-(z+\frac{1}{2})}=
\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}(z+\frac{1}{2})}=
\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n\,(z+\frac{1}{2})^n  
$$ 
Hope this helps.